# Url Routing without parameters in ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes, url-routing

I am using routing in aspnet webform. I have without parameters pages.
Sometimes the wrong page routing.
My code:

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Login", "", "~/Login.aspx");
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Logoff", "Logoff", "~/Logoff.aspx");
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("HomePage", "HomePage", "~/HomePage.aspx");
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("About", "About", "~/About.aspx");
```

I go to Login Page(just localhost),this execute truly. Then logged in route HomePage. When I click About page, it is not going to About page, going to Logoff.
My HomePage HyperLink:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:RouteName=About%>">About</asp:HyperLink>
```

I can't solved this problem.